# python os.getenv can't see variables defined in ~/.profile

Tags: linux, ubuntu, environment-variables, ubuntu-20.04, .profile

I'm trying to set some environment variables on the DigitalOcean droplet for my python project.

I put them to the `~/.profile` file. Now it looks like this:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi

PRODUCTION=1
```

After droplet reset, I tried to get the `PRODUCTION` in `python` script but it returns None.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getenv('PRODUCTION')
>>>
```

What I'm doing wrong? If not `.profile`, what file should I use to permanently set such variables?

Comment: Have you tried `export PRODUCTION=1` ?

Comment: As @nic3500 is hinting at, you haven't exported your shell variables to the environment. Running `somevar=1` creates a *shell* variable; it's not in the environment and won't be visible to child processes. You only get an environment variable if you explicitly `export` it.

Answer (score 1):

Posting an answer since I spent some time searching too

As both comments stated, you need to specifically export the variable in your `~/profile` file

```
# Use this
export MYVAR=1

# NOT this
MYVAR=1
```